# run a code while a word document is closing

Tags: c#

Is there any way to run a code when a word document is closing in c#? for example I wanna show a message box when a word document is closed in my desktop.

Comment: You mean to monitor a work of another program?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Marshal.GetActiveObject`

```
Application word = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
if(word == null)
{
   Console.Write("Your word is not started");
}
```

Msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work,I didn't understand your meaning about if(condition) . Can you tell me more about it please?